# PYQT5 Loading screen until main gui is initialized (frozen screen)

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to implement a loading screen that will be displayed in front of the main or application gui `Main_Window`.
The loading screen `Load_Window` should contain a gif image and a progress bar that continuously shows how far the main interface `Main_Window` has been initialized.
Once the main gui is fully initialized, then the loading screen should disappear and the main GUI be displayed.

[image: ProcessBar PyQt5]

So far I've tried the QThread, QSplashscreen and app.processEvent() approaches, but the loading screen was frozen because the pyqt5 event handler isn't running.

[image: frozen gui]

In the code example below I have shown the problem as an example.The code is executable!
The for loop in `Main_Window` is meant to represent starting configuration files, thread and initializing GUI etc.

How can I display and update the loading screen while the other GUI is being initialized?
How can I prevent this effect?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QDialog, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize

class Main_Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(640, 480))
        self.setWindowTitle("Main Window")

        centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        gridLayout = QGridLayout(self)
        centralWidget.setLayout(gridLayout)

        title = QLabel("I am the main window", self)
        title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        gridLayout.addWidget(title, 0, 0)

        #   Running the loading screen in own thread, but the event handler is the same :(
        # self.Thread = Thread_Load()
        # self.Thread.start()


        #   Call event handler to process the queue
        #app.processEvents()
        self.show()

        for i in range(0,1000000):
            print(i)
class Load_Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.setGeometry(0,0,500,500)

        self.setWindowTitle("Load Window")

        title = QLabel("I am the Load window", self)
        title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        title.move(200,200)
        self.show()

# class Thread_Load(QThread):
#     def __init__(self, parent=None):
#         QThread.__init__(self, parent)
#         Load_Window()
#     def run(self):
#         #   Call event handler to process the queue
#         while True:
#             app.processEvents()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    LoadWin = Load_Window()
    MainWin = Main_Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Widgets are not thread safe, you cannot access nor create them in external threads, only in the main thread. Also, `processEvents()` only works for objects in *that* thread, so doing it in another thread is pointless. You must call `processEvents()` *after* showing the loading window, and possibly only at certain intervals (so, not for every iteration of your `for` loop).

Answer (score 1):

Create a worker function `run()` to do all your works and change the values of two global flags as you go. I'm more comfortable with `threading` module. But you can find a similar implementation with `QThread` too.

```
import sys, time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QDialog, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize

alive, Progress = True, 0

class Main_Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(640, 480))
        self.setWindowTitle("Main Window")

        centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        gridLayout = QGridLayout(self)
        centralWidget.setLayout(gridLayout)

        title = QLabel("I am the main window", self)
        title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        gridLayout.addWidget(title, 0, 0)

        #   Running the loading screen in own thread, but the event handler is the same :(
        # self.Thread = Thread_Load()
        # self.Thread.start()


        #   Call event handler to process the queue
        #app.processEvents()
        self.show()

        #for i in range(0,1000000):
        #    print(i)

class Load_Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.setGeometry(0,0,500,500)

        self.setWindowTitle("Load Window")

        title = QLabel("I am the Load window", self)
        title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        title.move(200,200)
        self.show()

def run():
    global open, Progress
    time.sleep(3)
    #Do your stuff here, like change the value of Progress as you go through your for loop
    alive=False;

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    LoadWin = Load_Window()
    import threading
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target = run)
    thread1.start()
    while alive:
        time.sleep(.05)
        #Set progressbar value as the value of Progress.
        app.processEvents()
    LoadWin.close()
    MainWin=Main_Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is the comment left by @musicamante.

If you just wanted to unfreeze your LoadWin, all you need is to put processEvents() right after LoadWin

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    LoadWin = Load_Window()
    app.processEvents()
    MainWin = Main_Window()
    LoadWin.close()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you want to the loading screen to move while you trying to load your Main Window, you can send a pyqtSignal to the QDialog to indicate the milestone is achieved.

```
import sys, time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QDialog, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget, QProgressBar
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize

class Main_Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Progress = 10
        LoadWin.progressUpdate(Progress)
        time.sleep(2)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(640, 480))
        self.setWindowTitle("Main Window")

        centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        Progress = 30
        LoadWin.progressUpdate(Progress)
        time.sleep(2)

        gridLayout = QGridLayout(self)
        centralWidget.setLayout(gridLayout)
        Progress = 50
        LoadWin.progressUpdate(Progress)
        time.sleep(2)

        title = QLabel("I am the main window", self)
        title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        gridLayout.addWidget(title, 0, 0)

        #   Running the loading screen in own thread, but the event handler is the same :(
        # self.Thread = Thread_Load()
        # self.Thread.start()


        #   Call event handler to process the queue
        #app.processEvents()
        Progress = 100
        LoadWin.progressUpdate(Progress)
        self.show()
        LoadWin.close()

class Load_Window(QDialog):
    
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.setGeometry(0,0,500,500)
        self.setWindowTitle("Load Window")

        title = QLabel("I am the Load window", self)
        self.pbar = QProgressBar(self)
        
        self.pbar.setGeometry(30, 40, 200, 25)
        
        title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        title.move(200,200)
        self.show()

    def progressUpdate(self, progress):
        self.pbar.setValue(progress)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    LoadWin = Load_Window()
    app.processEvents()

    MainWin=Main_Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```